# Changing bin size of Histogram

Tags: vba, excel, charts, histogram

I want a macro that will enable me to determine the bid width of a histogram.

I recored the actions of changing the actual bin width, then inserted the input box to allow me to do this more dynamically.

```
Sub ChangeBinSize()

    myValue = InputBox("Choose the bin width for the Histogram ?")

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 4").Activate

    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Select

    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select

    ActiveChart.ChartGroups(1).BinWidthValue = myValue

End Sub
```

However, after running the macro nothing changes on the chart, where am I going wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't specify what version of Excel you are using.

You don't specify how you create the histogram.

If you are using the new Excel 2016 histogram chart, then you can't manipulate it with VBA, because this new chart type does not yet expose all its properties to the Excel VBA Object Model.

In earlier versions of Excel you can use the Analysis ToolPak to calculate the data and create resulting histogram charts.

In general, the built-in histogram charts of Excel are not well suited to dynamically changing source data.

You may want to hack this and build your own data model with dynamic bin sizes etc., then use dynamic range names to build Excel charts. Depending on your Excel version you can utilize the Power Pivot Data Model to help with the calculations.

Comment: Thanks, I had just assumed there would be more controls in VBA, i am going to create it using FREQUENCY, just makes it a little messier if i want to change it in the future

Comment: This hasn't changed so far.

Comment: Isn't that a pity that what worked in previous Excel Version does not work anymore. Don't we call that a "regression", something nobody want except when their are new functionality overwhelming the lost. 
So thanks to "cloud base" version, we pay more for having less functionalities (and not simpler usability) to change bins, I need 6 clicks and then type a number...)
Can't we use "Analysis ToolPak" on new Excel version ?

Comment: @2diabolos.com Backwards compatibility is one of the most important things Microsoft considers when adding new features. What part that used to work now doesn't?  All Excel legacy tools work with the current version, including the Analysis TookPak, but it has to be activated.